# downloading files with unicode characters in their names in php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I use laravel5 and windows7 for my web developing.I have some links in my views that after clicking on those users can download their desired files.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 flip pull-right">
    <a href="download/docs/ezharNameKarshenasi.docx" style="display: block;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;"><img src="images/docx.gif" />فرم اظهارنامه کارشناسی</a>
    <a href="download/docs/drakhasteSodoreParvaneTasis.docx" style="display: block;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;"><img src="images/docx.gif" />فرم درخواست صدور پروانه تاسیس</a>
    <a href="download/docs/taghazayeSodooreParvane.docx" style="display: block;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;"><img src="images/docx.gif" />فرم تقاضای صدور پروانه موافقت اصولی آبزیان</a>
    <a href="download/docs/sherkateSahamiIran.docx" style="display: block;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;"><img src="images/docx.gif" />فرم پروانه موافقت اصولی ماهیان سرد آبی در سیستم مدار بسته</a>
    <a href="download/docs/morafiName.docx" style="display: block;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;"><img src="images/docx.gif" />فرم معرفی نامه جهت در یافت اعتبارات بانکی</a>
    <a href="download/docs/نامه.docx" style="display: block;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;"><img src="images/docx.gif" />نامه</a>
</div>
```

but some files name have unicode characters in their names.for example:C:\wamp\www\shilat-sistanL5\public\docs\نامه.docx.

in my routes file I have added this codes:

```
Route::get('download/{type}/{filename}', function($type,$filename)
{

    $file = public_path() .'\\'.$type. '\\' . $filename; // or wherever you have stored your PDF files
    return response()->download($file);
});
```

when trying to download نامه.docx file, I encountered with this error:
FileNotFoundException in File.php line 37: The file "C:\wamp\www\shilat-sistanL5\public\docs\نامه.docx" does not exist.

I know this problem is related to php and not supporting utf-8 files. Anyone has a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with PHP but I had an almost identical problem with JSP.
The way I solved it was by encoding the URL.

For Java I used a library from owasp

```
public static String paramEncode(String param) {
    return org.owasp.encoder.Encode.forUriComponent(param);
}
```

But for PHP I think you can use something like

```
string urlencode ( string $str )
```

See http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php